# Which font was used for the site's headline?

Tags: discussion

Which font was used for the site's headline "ENGLISH LANGUAGE & USAGE"?

(I like it.)

Comment: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/400/english-site-design Doesn't mention the font, as far as I could tell, but provides some background history.

Comment: Found the answer in this link: [What font does the site use?](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2809/what-font-does-the-site-use?rq=1)

Comment: @Mari-LouA: that link only gives the body font (Georgia). The heading is a graphic, and obviously uses a different font than the rest of the site.

Comment: @Marthaª I hadn't realized. I just recalled reading about the font used for ELU and found the link. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 5):

The ampersand is **Baskerville Italic.** The main font is a type of distressed/corroded **Caslon**, which is given away by the serif at the top of the A, especially.

There are some demonstrated at http://www.fontscape.com/explore?7QI, but not the particular example used here.

Comment: Hopefully Jin will call in at some point...